# Fake multi-monitor fullscreen in monogame: form can't be big enough

Tags: c#, windows, monogame, managed-directx

I run a triple-monitor setup and I am working on a graphics demo in MonoGame that I decided (heck why not?  let's give it the ability to maximize across all displays!) so I used this code:

```
 graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        //get dimensions of box that will cover all displays and set window to it.
        int xPos = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.OrderBy(x => x.Bounds.X).Select(x => x.Bounds.X).First();
        int yPos = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.OrderBy(y => y.Bounds.Y).Select(y => y.Bounds.Y).First();
        form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        form.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xPos, yPos);
        int xWidth = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.OrderByDescending(x => x.Bounds.X).Select(x => x.Bounds.X + x.Bounds.Width).First() - xPos;
        int yHeight = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.OrderByDescending(y => y.Bounds.Y).Select(y => y.Bounds.Y + y.Bounds.Height).First() - yPos;
        form.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);

        form.Width = xWidth;
        form.Height = yHeight;
      //  graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = xWidth;
     //   graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = yHeight;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        Properties.Settings.Default.FakeFullScreen = true;
    }
```

and of course a 2nd function to undo it.

This worked fine when I had one of my monitors set above the others for testing, but when I set windows layout to place them all side-by-side (giving a resolution of 5760x1080) I was throwing an invalid parameter error on the graphics.ApplyChanges().  So I commented out the graphics code and set the form width manually and discovered that evidently I am not allowed to have a form wider than 4096 pixels.

Is there a way around this?  I am open to all suggestions, including having more than one window side-by-side to draw to, but I would need some code to show me how to target a 2nd form.

Please and thank you.

Comment: I cannot help you with your specific question, but I would recommend to reconsider your requirement:

A multi-monitor setup often results in a non-rectangular configuration overall. As I write this, I have a 1920x1200 monitor next to my 1920x1080 notebook screen. So if your algorithm works as you expect, a significant portion of your window would be invisible to me.

Comment: that was expected.  the non-visible areas wouldn't be drawn to.  It's simply a graphics demo that draws patterns on the screen, and this is one of the expected ways of doing this to a non-standard monitor layout.  My code not only returns the monitors, but their visible pixel range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a DirectX 9/Windows Phone 7 limitation of texture sizes limited to 4096 x 4096 by the use of the "Reach Graphics Profile".

The final displayed image is a single texture of the composite of all spritebatches, the size cannot exceed the maximum texture size.

To correct the issue:

1. Make sure your video card supports larger textures: run dxdiag.exe (most modern video cards do, given enough memory).
2. Enable the "[hidef](http://community.monogame.net/t/opengl-directx-reach-hidef-basics/7681)" profile to allow full DX9, DX10, and DX11 modes.

To enable "Hidef", modify your `Game1.cs` constructor use [this code](http://community.monogame.net/t/solved-does-the-hidef-profile-work-correctly-in-monogame-3-6/9149):

```
public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            graphics.GraphicsProfile = GraphicsProfile.HiDef;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
            // any additional code goes here
        }
```

---

The alternative is to use OpenGL, which ignores the graphics profile and uses the optimal version for your video card.

Comment: i can't "accept" your answer since it's wrong (it's code for xna) but it did point me in the direction i needed to go.  Up-vote.  The profile switching is possible but done totally differently.

Comment: The code came directly from the MonoGame website.  I made the assumption that the code given above would be placed after `//any additional code goes here` and thus `ApplyChanges()` would have been called(multiple times, although, only the last one is necessary). If the above code does not work(with your code under it), please let me know, and I will submit an issue with MonoGame.

Comment: ok well i don't know what i did but for thoroughness i retested your code again and it does in fact work.  I must have put it in the wrong place originally.  I will correct this heinous error and give you the credit.